# Access data from previously submitted values in buildForm in FormBase plugin

Tags: 8, plugins

I have a FormBase plugin for an admin configuration page. My desired behavior is to select a series of checkboxes and when you submit the form based on those values a new set of fields will show. However I'm not sure how to build the form after submitting the form with new values.

Here's my current buildForm function

```
    $form['pages'] = [
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => 'Pages to clone:',
        '#options' => [
            'about' => 'About',
            'home' => 'Home',
            'blog' => 'Blog',
        ],
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];
```

(Sidenote: Not sure if or why the last bit with the 'actions' is necessary) The form is build fine and in my submitForm function I have

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->set('pages', $form_state->getValue());
    $form_state->set('test_parameter', 'test_value');
}
```

However when I add a var_dump($form_state) to the buildForm function and submit the form like so

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        var_dump($form_state);
        $form_state->set('pages', $form_state->getValue());
        $form_state->set('test_parameter', 'test_value');
}

I get some information about the form_state but nothing about the parameters I set.

> object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)#599 (33) {
>   ["complete_form":protected]=>   NULL   ["build_info":protected]=>
>   array(4) {
>       ["args"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["files"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["callback_object"]=>
>       object(Drupal\my_plugin\Form\PageCloner)#600 (10) {
>         ["number":protected]=>
>         int(1)
>         ["requestStack":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["configFactory":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["routeMatch":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["_serviceIds":protected]=>
>         array(0) {
>         }
>         ["linkGenerator":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["loggerFactory":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["redirectDestination":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["stringTranslation":protected]=>
>         NULL
>         ["urlGenerator":protected]=>
>         NULL
>       }
>       ["form_id"]=>
>       string(9) "page_pack"   }   ["rebuild_info":protected]=>   array(0) {   }   ["rebuild":protected]=>   bool(false)
>   ["invalidToken":protected]=>   bool(false)   ["response":protected]=> 
>   NULL   ["redirect":protected]=>   NULL   ["no_redirect":protected]=>
>   NULL   ["method":protected]=>   string(4) "POST"
>   ["requestMethod":protected]=>   string(3) "GET"
>   ["cache":protected]=>   bool(false)   ["no_cache":protected]=>   NULL 
>   ["values":protected]=>   array(0) {   }
>   ["cleanValueKeys":protected]=>   array(4) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(7) "form_id"
>       [1]=>
>       string(10) "form_token"
>       [2]=>
>       string(13) "form_build_id"
>       [3]=>
>       string(2) "op"   }   ["input":protected]=>   array(0) {   }   ["always_process":protected]=>   NULL   ["must_validate":protected]=> 
>   NULL   ["programmed":protected]=>   bool(false)
>   ["programmed_bypass_access_check":protected]=>   bool(true)
>   ["process_input":protected]=>   NULL   ["submitted":protected]=>
>   bool(false)   ["executed":protected]=>   bool(false)
>   ["triggering_element":protected]=>   NULL
>   ["has_file_element":protected]=>   NULL   ["groups":protected]=>
>   array(0) {   }   ["storage":protected]=>   array(0) {   }
>   ["buttons":protected]=>   array(0) {   }   ["temporary":protected]=>
>   array(0) {   }   ["validation_complete":protected]=>   bool(false)
>   ["errors":protected]=>   array(0) {   }
>   ["limit_validation_errors":protected]=>   NULL
>   ["validate_handlers":protected]=>   array(0) {   }
>   ["submit_handlers":protected]=>   array(0) {   } }

What is the best way to get information retrieved in the formSubmit function back to when the buildForm function is fired again after submit? Or is there a better way I'm not considering to create a new form based on these values?

UPDATE: 4k4's solution worked but I ran into another issue where the form state wasn't properly saving. I resolved this by adding

```
parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
```

to the submitForm function before $form_state->setRebuild(); this led to an error saying

> Cannot call abstract method
>   Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::submitForm()

to resolve that I changed the form from extending FormBase to extending ConfigFormBase instead like so

```
class MyPlugin extends ConfigFormBase {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rebuild the form with the values of `$form_state` you have to set the form to be rebuilt after processing:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->set('test_parameter', 'test_value');
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Otherwise the form redirects to a new form build.